# Is it possible to switch the positions of the tab bar and the sherlock action bar?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-tabs

It is possible to switch the positions of the action bar and tab bar from action bar sherlock so that the tabs appear above the action bar?

Answer (score 0):

Playing with the ABS demo app, it seems to do just that if you don't have a logo or Home action (just title).